# Rewrite rule to update image path using htaccess?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Currently working on a website where the urls always starts with a language code and a country code. Example: http://www.website.com/en/nl/.

This upsets the relative CSS, JS and Image paths. I can't change the base href because all the dynamic page URL's need to be included with this language and country code. I can easily update the sources for CSS and JS but the images are a problem because they are loaded from different modules and I can't rebuild all those modules.

I want to create a rewrite rule that removes the first two parts of the url, only for images.

So:
website.com/en/nl/images/image.jpg => website.com/images/image.jpg
website.com/de/fr/uploads/image.png =>website.com/uploads/image.png

The image folder can differ, same goes for the language and country code.

Can you guys help me out with this? With my lack of experience with Regex I can't figure out the correct rule.

**Solution**:
A guy helped me with it, solution is:

RewriteRule ^(..)/(..)/(.*.)(gif|jpg|png|doc|docx|pdf|css|flv|js|swf|php)$ $3$4 [L]

(can't answer this post for 7 more hours)

Answer (score 0):

Why do this with a rewrite url? If the static resources are always in the root just use the root like "/uploads/image.png" instead of the full domain name.

Comment: Because the base href is with the country and language code (should've mentioned that)

Comment: Using /uploads/image.png instead of uploads/image.png on the page website.com/en/nl/info.html will try to load website.com/uploads/image.png. This matches your desired situation as mention in your post.